# React Router not updating content on url change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have tried a couple of solutions I found on StackOverflow but as of yet nothing has worked. When I navigate to a designer from the 'our designers' dropdown in the navigation it works for the first time. If I open the nav and again try a different designer, the url changes but nothing else happens. I'm using React Router v4.

This is how i'm initially getting the content:

```
 updateDesigner() {
  Data.map((designer, id) => {
    if (`?${designer.title.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('')}` === 
      this.props.location.search){
         this.setState({
            title: designer.title,
            blurb: designer.blurb,
            sale: designer.sale,
            dresses: designer.dresses
          });
        }
        return false;
 });
}

componentWillMount() {
 this.updateDesigner();
}
```

In the Navigation component I have this function for when a designer is clicked:

```
 handleDesignerClick(d) {
    const title = d.title.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('');
    this.props.history.replace({
        pathname: '/designer',
        search: title
});
```

The site is very much a work in progress but i've uploaded it [Here](http://amoraeoccasions.co.uk/) if you need to dig deeper.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try this but it didn't work! Had the same result as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) can be leveraged to compare current and previous query strings in order to detect changes in [`location`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/location) for instances where components are not dismounted.

```
// Did Update.
componentDidUpdate(previousProps) {
  const currentSearch = this.props.location.search
  const previousSearch = previousProps.location.search
  if (currentSearch !== previousSearch) updateDesigner()
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I had tried using the componentDidUpdate() but was clearly using it incorrectly. 
`I was just using: componentDidUpdate(){
    this.updateDesigner()
}`

Thanks mate! :)